# How to call in Javascript a requestAnimationFrame loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I watched a *[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zucCjXApXOU)* describing how to use requestAnimationFrame to loop a animation. I tried to replicate it and believe I am very close but am missing a key point. When I click the "box" the onclick="loopKeyFrame()" activates and calls runKeyFrame() only once?

My intention was to loop runKeyframe() infinitely with this code. I know I can put "infinite" in the css to make it run forever but thats not the point. im trying to use requestAnimationFrame as was used in the video.

My code in *[CodePen](http://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/ZOmGGN)*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RequestAnimation Lesson</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: grey;
}

#box {
position:relative;
width:30px;
border:1px solid blue;
background-color:blue;
height:10px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}

@keyframes myMove {
0%{left:0%;}
50%{left:95%;}
100%{left:0%;}
}
</style>
<script>

function runKeyFrame() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.animation = "myMove 4s";
}

function loopKeyFrame() {
   runKeyFrame();
   requestAnimationFrame(loopKeyFrame);
}



</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box" onclick="loopKeyFrame()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add and remove a `className` instead of setting `style` of element, use `setTimeout` to call `requestAnimationFrame` with `loopKeyFrame` as parameter after four seconds.

```js
function runKeyFrame() {
  document.getElementById("box").className = "myMove";
}

function loopKeyFrame() {
  runKeyFrame();
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("box").className = ""
    requestAnimationFrame(loopKeyFrame)
  }, 4000)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.myMove {
  animation: myMove 4s;
}

@keyframes myMove {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 95%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="loopKeyFrame()"></div>
```

---

You could alternatively use [`.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate), [`finish`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/onfinish) event handler to recursively call `loopKeyFrame`

```js
var animation;

function runKeyFrame() {
  return document.getElementById("box")
    .animate([{
      left: "0%"
    }, {
      left: "95%"
    }, {
      left: "0%"
    }], {
      duration: 4000,
      iterations: 1
    });
}

function loopKeyFrame() {
  animation = runKeyFrame();
  animation.onfinish = loopKeyFrame;
}

document.querySelector("button")
.addEventListener("click", function() { 
  animation.cancel()
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="loopKeyFrame()"></div><br>
<button>cancel</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the in-depth fix. but i did learn a valuable lesson. you CANNOT use requestAnimationFrame on a @keyframe... it would be super convenient thought if that fixed it so you could though

Comment: why the use of rAF if you do wrap it in setTimeout ?

Comment: @Kaiido To request that browser perform animation before next repaint.

Comment: yep but you already waited approximately 4 seconds, so who cares about the next screen refresh at this point ? It's just the same to use a setTimeout(0). And it's not needed either, calling it directly will do to. rAF is good if you do some operation at screen refresh rate, but all screens refresh faster than every 4 seconds.

Comment: @Kaiido _"yep but you already waited approximately 4 seconds, so who cares about the next screen refresh at this point ? It's just the same to use a setTimeout(0)"_ Have you tried approach at stacksnippets  calling `loopKeyFrame()`  within `setTimeout` without passing `loopKeyFrame`  reference to  `requestAnimationFrame`? `setTimeout(loopKeyFrame, 0)` does not return same result at `requestAnimationFrame(loopKeyFrame)`

Comment: Yes, in this case, rAF and setTimeout will suffer the same problem : they may fire before the browser has parsed the class of your element and may not add the animation to the element before you removed it. Here is the [setTimeout(0)](https://jsfiddle.net/2yautu5u/1/). The best approach is to keep everything inline, but to call `elem.offsetTop` which will force the browser to repaint your element, hence will attach the animation at each loop : https://jsfiddle.net/2yautu5u/

Comment: not on my FF no, I've got only 1/3 loops firing correctly, which is a normal behavior.

Comment: @Kaiido Interesting. chromium does not pause. Your suggested solution is using `elem.offsetTop` is the stable approach. Initially considered requirement was to not use `infinite` at `css`. `javascript` could be removed; `html`, `css` could be used to achieve same result with `infinite` at `css`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be running just fine. But what you told it to do isn't necessarily what you wanted it to do.

To demonstrate, try using `<div id="box" onclick="runKeyFrame()"></div>` instead. It will only seem to register the first time.

This is because setting `.style.animation` to the value it already contains isn't exactly going to achieve anything.

`requestAnimationFrame` is usually combined with JavaScript animations, not CSS ones. To work with CSS animations in JavaScript, you will need the `animationEnd` event, most likely.

Comment: Ive tried <div id="box" onclick="runKeyFrame()"></div>, but your saying requestAnimationFrame cannot loop a css @keyFrame animation? If thats the case ill simply just create the animation in JS but I wna be sure before I continue.

Comment: It's not the right way to do your loop, no. Either use `infinite` in the CSS, or use `animationEnd` to trigger a restart, or just implement the animation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I was able to come up with this: *[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/QEJNgz)*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RequestAnimation Lesson</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: grey;
}

#box {
position:relative;
width:30px;
border:1px solid blue;
background-color:blue;
height:10px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
@keyframes myMove {
0%{left:0%;}
50%{left:95%;}
100%{left:0%;}
}
</style> 
<script>

function runKeyFrame() {
document.getElementById("box").style.animation = "myMove 4s infinite"; 
}

function stopAnimation() {
document.getElementById("box").style.animation = "none";
}





</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="runKeyFrame()">Start Animation</button>
<button onclick="stopAnimation()">Stop Animation</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```